# OS process sampler and response assertion

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter, I have one perl script which I am calling from testcase (I am using autoshell property of jmeter and to execute the script) and which will execute at server side ( remote machine) not at jmeter machine, Problem is once that script is being executed at remote machine, I should able to catch the response i.e. return 1 or return 0 whatever it is.. Since the script is running at server its hard to catch the return 0 or return 1 in jmeter and based on this return values I have to decide whether my test case is pass or fail. I thought to use OS sampler I don't know how useful it will be in this case and for response I thought I will use response assertion but being new to jmeter its hard for me to find out the solution. Can I get some initial level of help, How can I do it.. If anything is not clear please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You can use OS Sampler, it has a `Return code configuration` in it. You can select "check return code" and set the expected return code. The JMeter thread waits until a return code is received. You can also use Response Assertion to check the script output. Only downside with using OS Sampler is you need to start JMeter server agent at the remote machine and then only can run it.

You can also try [SSH Command](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-ssh-sampler/). It helps in executing commands in linux box and don't need a server start as well.

Comment: Thanks Shubra... I have download "jmeter-ssh-sampler" i.e.  jmeter-ssh-sampler-0.1.0.jar and then "jsch-0.1.52.jar" I have kept both the files in jmeter's /lib dir.. restarted the jmeter but in sampler category I am not finding the SSH sampler ?? any comments on this??

Comment: jmeter-ssh-sampler-0.1.0.jar should be copied in lib\ext. And jsch-0.1.52.jar should be copied under lib. Then restart jmeter

Comment: Please also check your jmeter version. It suggest •JMeter 2.3+ is capable of running this plugin